# Using cylindrical shells to find volume

Tags: calculus

> Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume $V$ of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the $x$-axis: $x = 4 + (y − 6)^2,  x = 13$.

Comment: So what is _your_ question? What have you tried? What you have learned in class related to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this is generated about the x axis, you want the function to be stated as $y = \sqrt{x-4} + 6$

This function is not defined below x = 4 so the limits of integration are from 4 to 13.

I'm anticipating this was the holdup in you starting this problem and you know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the limits of $y$.

- The limits of $y$ are found by solving $13 = 4 + (y-6)^2$ for $y = 3 \ldots 9$.

Each cylindrical shell is defined for a value of $y$ as having length between $x=4 + (y-6)^2$ and $x=13$, or

$${\rm d}A = 2 \pi y \left((13) - (4+(y-6)^2)\right)\,{\rm d}y$$

To get the volume, you need the integral of the shell areas

$$ {\rm d}V = 2 \pi \int \limits_3^9 y \left(9 - (y-6)^2 \right) {\rm d}y $$